# How to make groups in MSSQL tree with CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, tree, rank, recursive-cte

I have a problem with creating tree with my entities.

There are entities with entity id which are connected with other entities by `parent_ent_id`.

My input is

| ent_id | ent_name | parent_ent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | GSM_FACTORY | NULL |
| 2 | Maszyna_1 | 1 |
| 5 | Maszyna_2 | 1 |
| 7 | GSM_FACTORY_2 | NULL |
| 11 | Maszyna_3 | 7 |
| 12 | Maszyna_4 | 7 |

And with my code

```
WITH genealogy AS 
(
    SELECT 
        ent_id, ent_name,
        parent_ent_id,
        can_track_oee,
        0 AS generation_number,
        0 as par,
        CAST('0' AS varchar(50)) AS dens,
        CAST('0_' + CAST(ent_id AS varchar(50)) AS varchar(50)) AS order_sequence   
    FROM 
        ent
    WHERE 
        parent_ent_id IS NULL
 
    UNION ALL
 
    SELECT 
        child.ent_id, child.ent_name,
        child.parent_ent_id,
        child.can_track_oee,
        generation_number + 1 AS generation_number,
        par + 1,
        CAST(dens + '_' +
            CAST(
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY child.parent_ent_id)
            AS VARCHAR(50)
        ) AS VARCHAR(50)) AS dens,

        CAST(order_sequence + '_' + CAST(child.ent_id AS VARCHAR (50)) AS VARCHAR(50)) AS order_sequence
    FROM 
        ent child
    JOIN 
        genealogy g ON g.ent_id = child.parent_ent_id
)
SELECT * 
FROM genealogy
```

I'm getting something like this as a result:

| ent_id | ent_name | parent_ent_id | can_track_oee | generation_number | par | dens | order_sequence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | GSM_FACTORY | NULL | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0_1 |
| 7 | GSM_FACTORY_2 | NULL | 0 0 | 0 | 0 | 0_7 |  |
| 11 | Maszyna_3 | 7 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0_1 | 0_7_11 |
| 12 | Maszyna_4 | 7 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0_1 | 0_7_12 |
| 2 | Maszyna_1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0_1 | 0_1_2 |
| 5 | Maszyna_2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0_1 | 0_1_5 |

Why do I have dens like 0_1 0_1 0_1 0_1 and not like 0_1 0_1 0_2 0_2

Comment: The problem is that the `DENSE_RANK` is only calculated per each row output from the preceding recursion level, not over the whole set. This is documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#guidelines-for-defining-and-using-recursive-common-table-expressions. Also I don't get your results exactly, see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3ed374183142f7d4613307204e135e24, and `can_track_oee` is missing from your sample data (it seems irrelevant so I rmeoved it from the query)

Comment: What you *can* do, is assign on the first level a row-number, then for each set of child rows *per row of the previous set* assign a new row-number. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c436c17cf80a5d4bc3bfcc4c4037b038. You cannot assign a row-number across different sets of recursion, as the recursion works row-by-row, not in sets.